# Restrict Staffs to Login in Laravel in both system

Tags: laravel

I've create a 2 (two) system and 2 subdomain with the same Database
but the staff they can login in both system, and i want to disable the staff not to login in the other system.

please let me know if anyone can do this. im new to Laravel World

Thanks

Comment: You can use two middleware one for staff and another for admin. If you don't have idea about middleware then read this link 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

Comment: permission + roles + middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a `instance_id` field to the `User` model.

On the first application, add to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`:

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $success = $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );

    return ($success && $this->userExistsInApplication());
}


/**
 * Determine if the user exists for the specified application
 *
 * @return bool
 */
private function userExistsInApplication()
{
    if ($this->guard()->user()->instance_id == env('APP_INSTANCE'))
        return true;

    $this->guard()->user()->logout();

    return false;
}
```

Add to `.env`:

```
APP_INSTANCE=1
```

On the **second** application, add to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`:

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $success = $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );

    return ($success && $this->userExistsInApplication());
}


/**
 * Determine if the user exists for the specified application
 *
 * @return bool
 */
private function userExistsInApplication()
{
    if ($this->guard()->user()->instance_id == env('APP_INSTANCE'))
        return true;

    $this->guard()->user()->logout();

    return false;
}
```

Add to `.env`:

```
APP_INSTANCE=2
```

Set which instance the user is able to log into based on their value set in `instance_id`.